# How to make a DIV with variable height push down content coming after?

Tags: css, html, positioning

DIV1 (relative positioning) has a variable number of other DIVS (absolute positioning) inside of it. The quantity of these absolute divs depends on how many items are retrieved out of a database. Therefore I cannot specify a height for DIV1. As a result, content after DIV1 (such as table 'section2' end up beneath the divs.

Is there a simple way to make DIV1 push down any content coming after. Thx.

```
<div id='DIV1' style='position:relative;'>
  <div style='position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:285px;height:74px;'>
  ....
</div>

<table id='SECTION2'>
<tr>
<td>ITEM A</td>
<td>ITEM B</td>
<td>ITEM C</td>
<td>ITEM D</td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple (non-javascript) way as long as the contents are absolutely positioned. You should rethink your design so these items use relative or static (normal) positioning.

The whole point of absolute positioning is to have no effect on the rest of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this below div1 and above section2

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: he didn't say they were floated.

Comment: Oops, didn't see that. I thought they were floated. Spliff is right, you'll need to change your positioning.